Top and center vertical alignment columns in longtable
I am trying to get a longtable where one column is vertically and horizontally centered and another column vertically top aligned and horizontally ragged right. So I defined two column types:
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1\linewidth}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1\linewidth}}

However, the result is not as expected. It appears that only the new L column type does anything. Here is my MWE:
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\definecolor{mbsblue}{RGB}{22,84,138}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1\linewidth}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1\linewidth}}
\addtolength\aboverulesep{0.15ex} 
\addtolength\belowrulesep{0.35ex}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}[c]{C{0.15}L{.3}L{.3}}                                                    
  \rowcolor{mbsblue}{\color{white}\textbf{Header 1}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{C{.3}}{\color{white}\textbf{H2}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{C{.3}}{\color{white}\textbf{Longer Header to Wrap}}\\\addlinespace\endhead
  Center 1 & Item 1 \newline Item 2 & Thing 1  \newline Thing 2\\\midrule                  
  0   Center 2 &  Item 3 \newline Item 4 \newline Item 5 & Thing 3 \newline Thing 4 \\\midrule
\end{longtable} 
\end{document}  

Here is what it looks like:

The second column is correct - it is ragged right and top aligned. However, the first column (of type C) is also top aligned. The horizontal centering is correct, but not the top alignment. The C definition uses m, which is what I would expect to work.
What is odd to me, is that when I change the L definition to also be vertically centered, it changes both column types. Here is the new MWE:
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\definecolor{mbsblue}{RGB}{22,84,138}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1\linewidth}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1\linewidth}}
\addtolength\aboverulesep{0.15ex} 
\addtolength\belowrulesep{0.35ex}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}[c]{C{0.15}L{.3}L{.3}}                                                    
  \rowcolor{mbsblue}{\color{white}\textbf{Header 1}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{C{.3}}{\color{white}\textbf{H2}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{C{.3}}{\color{white}\textbf{Longer Header to Wrap}}\\\addlinespace\endhead
  Center 1 & Item 1 \newline Item 2 & Thing 1  \newline Thing 2\\\midrule                  
  0   Center 2 &  Item 3 \newline Item 4 \newline Item 5 & Thing 3 \newline Thing 4 \\\midrule
\end{longtable} 
\end{document}  

As you can see, I only changed the L definition. Here is the result:

As you can see, this changed all three of the columns. It changed the L type as well as the C type. Why? Is it not possible to have columns in a longtable with different vertical alignment?
This question suggested to use W alignment. But shouldn't the m specification also work?
According to the first comment here, the final column must be centered relative to the baseline. This Answer is then cited as explanation. But the problem is that in both of these, the last column is the "longest". But in my case, the middle column is the "longest". I want the last column to be "top" justified. Is the problem that my first column only has one line? If I use the tikz trick to find the baseline:
\tikz[overlay]\draw[red](0,0)--++(20,0);

Then this is what I see:

So clearly the issue is the placement of the baseline. So how do I "move" the baseline so that the first column is vertically centered?

the problem is aligning the third column. as far as I know, there is no automatic way to do that using standard features of the format and longtable/array. what you need is a box with the height/depth adjusted or the ability to use coffins rather than old-style boxes. the problem is there is no out-of-the-box point to anchor the third column vertically. what you want is either t or T of the second column's cell, but that's not exposed by the standard positional parameters, which are all relative to the baseline.

the easiest way is just to add a dummy line to the third column ....

possibly tabularray can do it? I would look, but Zarko or somebody will have answered before I get the manual open :-).

The package tabularray can let you achieve this complex alignment (link to documentation). A small issue is compilation takes significantly more time.
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\definecolor{mbsblue}{RGB}{22,84,138}

\addtolength\aboverulesep{0.15ex} 
\addtolength\belowrulesep{0.35ex}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtblr}[
        caption = {Caption of the table},
    ]
    {
        colspec = {
            Q[c,wd=0.15\linewidth]
            Q[l,wd=0.3\linewidth]
            Q[l,wd=0.3\linewidth]
        },
        hline{3-Z} = {},
        cells = {valign=h},
        row{1} = {
            font=\bfseries,
            bg=mbsblue,
            fg=white,
            halign=c,
            valign=m,
        },
        column{1} = {valign=m},
        rowhead = 1,
    }
    Header 1   & H2 & {Longer Header\\to Wrap} \\
    Center 1   & {Item 1\\Item 2\\Item 3} & {Thing 1\\Thing 2} \\
    0 Center 1 & {Item 4\\Item 5\\Item 6} & {Thing 3\\Thing 4} \\
    1 Center 2 & {Item 7\\Item 8\\Item 9\\Item 10} & {Thing 5\\Thing 6\\Thing 7} \\
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}



Thanks, I like this. I did not know that tabularray had a long version!

Edited v2
Ultimately, I don't know exactly what you're looking to achieve, but if it's just a matter of changing the vertical and horizontal alignment with merged lines, I strongly recommend that you use the multirow package rather than the \newline command.
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{multirow}

\definecolor{mbsblue}{RGB}{22,84,138} 
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1\linewidth}} 
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1\linewidth}} 
\addtolength\aboverulesep{0.15ex} 
\addtolength\belowrulesep{0.35ex} 

\begin{document} 

\begin{longtable}[c]{C{0.15}L{.3}L{.3}} 
\rowcolor{mbsblue}{\color{white}\textbf{Header 1}} & \multicolumn{1}{C{.3}}{\color{white}\textbf{H2}} & \multicolumn{1}{C{.3}}{\color{white}\textbf{Longer Header to Wrap}}\\
\addlinespace
\multirow{2}{*}{Center 1} & Item 1 & Thing 1 \\
& Item 2 & Thing 2
\\\midrule 
\multirow{3}{*}{Center 2} & Item 3 & Thing 3 \\
& Item 4  & Thing 4 \\
& Item 5 &
\\\midrule 
\end{longtable} 

\end{document}



If your table is very long, you can even create a macro that will replace * in the 2nd argument of multirow so that you can quickly change the horizontal alignment if several merged rows are involved
Please tell me if this is what you are trying to achieve or if it is more subtle than that?
